# 404 page returning 302

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I am running a WordPress site and my 404 page is returning a 302. It got me stumped how to fix the problem, looking at other sites it seems to be a common problem. My other site was fixed by my then SEO guys but I can't find out how they fixed it.

I have tried to fix it in the .htaccess by adding:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://aaamarketservices.com.au/404-page-something-went-wrong-page-not-found/
```

but the WordPress entry:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Stops the ErrorDocument 404 from working, without the WordPress entry of course WordPress won't work.

Comment: You might have more success in asking this on [wordpress.se], rather than here, but be sure to read their on-topic page first. For Stack Overflow, you have not provided enough information. For here, you will need to provide a [mcve] which duplicates the problem. As is stated in #1 on this page in the [help/on-topic], debugging questions must "include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself".

Comment: Thanks I will - what I am trying to do is get the 404 page to return a 404 rather than a 302.